# why mysql workbench say "with encryption" is not valid posiotion in this version on vesion 8 mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE #EncryptSP
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
SELECT TOP 10 City
FROM Person.Address
GO
```

why mysql workbench say "with encryption" is not valid posiotion in this version on vesion 8 mysql?
please harry it is assignment i cant find anything on internet about this

Comment: That is NOT a MySQL Query !!! TOP is a SQLServer function

Comment: And MySQL WorkBench does not work on SQLServer, if you are using SQLServer OR SQLServer specific commands dont work on MySQL

Comment: That's right, Microsoft SQL Server has an option for `CREATE PROCEDURE ... WITH ENCRYPTION` but MySQL does not have the same option. Please understand that Microsoft and MySQL are two different software products, and they have different features. You need to study the [documentation for CREATE PROCEDURE for MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) if you use that product. Even though they both support the SQL language, please understand that every implementation of SQL is different. Vendors can implement a subset of the standard, or extend it with custom features.